# Pull ASPX.NET Code From Database

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can pull code from a database field and have it rendered on the website. For example I pull the following from a field in the Database:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
Height="324px" Width="849px" Palette="EarthTones">
<Series>
       <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="UserID" YValueMembers="AvgAvail" XAxisType="Primary" IsValueShownAsLabel="true">
        </asp:Series>
</Series>
       <ChartAreas>
       <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
       <AxisX Interval="1"><MajorGrid Enabled="false" /></AxisX>
       </asp:ChartArea>
       </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="DELETED" SelectCommand="REALLYLONG"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And I want .NET to render the chart.

Here is the front end:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" /></Triggers>
<ContentTemplate><%=MainTile %>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So basically in the PageLoad() event I pull the code from the DB Field and then set it =MainTile and have the chart rendered. Currently it is just placing the ASP code into the page source.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the ParseControl function...

Here is a some code I use all the time to render a page template from code stored in the database.  It builds out the entire control tree.  Its great!

```
Template t = new Template(templateId);
Control c = ParseControl(t.TemplateContent);
Page.Controls.Add(c);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - could you possible send me a full example of how you do that?

Comment: I was able to get this to mostly work but I'm foggy on how to control where on the page the control is placed. Right now its being added to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a million you just shaved a ton of time off this project.


'<PlaceHolder id='derp'></Placeholder>'
'Controls c = ParseCOntrols((string)dbReader["Tile_Content"]);
'derp.controls.add(c)'

Comment: Not a problem.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to load chart appearance - you can have static chart control in your ASPX markup and simple load the appearance data via "Chart.Serializer.Load()" method.